# I want to take over PC's in my Active directory

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

Is it possible to have something like with terminal services to take over a Pc while its running?
so you can help someone with what they are doing? 
and preform some help. or is there something smarter or do i need to install vnc on all the computers?

Answer (score 6):

Everybody seems to forget Windows Remote Assistance - it's free and already built into the operating system.

Comment: +1 And you can shadow RDP sessions if they're on a windows server or actual terminal server.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few moments research on your own would tell you the answer to your question is "Yes".

Have a look at [lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com/). It does a lot of network management type things including solving the remote control issue. I'm sure someone else will come along to throw their favourite app into the hat as well, but you'll need to think about your requirements further in order to figure out which one best meets your need.