# what would be the ideal remote desktop support software

Tags: remote, vnc, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to take over PC's in my Active directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/180201/i-want-to-take-over-pcs-in-my-active-directory)

Domain : windows 2003
Workstations : windows 7 & few XP

Any highly recommended remote desktop support softwares, i have been trying this software called RealVNC however it does not support enough in the windows 7 workstations. really appreciate any solid resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at TeamViewer (http://www.teamviewer.com/), it doesn't need to be installed as a service, the user can start it when they want and gives a private connection to the remote machine.

We're using them extensively for remote desktop support, it gives you some very nice extras like chat with the remote desktop.

Comment: Teamviewer good software for the need. +1

Comment: well is it more secure?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) is best for this. Works locally and can use native authentication for connections.

Comment: ultra VNC is giving problems with windows7, it is ultra slow i guess even after installing aero drivers.

Answer (score 0):

We use Dameware as it is reasonably priced and works well for systems we have on the Domain.  It is priced per tech so you can have it on your PC and a laptop or two and be license compliant  It does need a port open in a firewall.  Not an issue for us as we have full contol of that as needed. [Dameware](http://www.dameware.com)